# Tight bounds for $L_1$ norm of Hermite polynomial: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\operatorname{He}_n(x)| \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2} ) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, normal-distribution, hermite-polynomials

Is there a closed-form expression (or tight upper bound) for the integral
$$C^{(1)}_n =\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\operatorname{He}_n(x)|  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2} \right) \mathrm dx$$
Here  $\operatorname{He}_n$ is a Hermite polynomial (probabilists' version).

Motivation: we know that
\begin{align}
C_n^{(2)}=\sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\operatorname{He}_n(  x)|^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2} \right) \mathrm dx }=  \sqrt{ n!}
\end{align}

I am curious in how different is $C^{(1)}_n$ from $C^{(2)}_n$. Using Jensen's inequality, it is not difficult to show that
\begin{align}
\frac{C_n^{(1)}}{C_n^{(2)}} \le 1
\end{align}

I am curious if there is a more refined bounds, for example, the one that would exactly characterize what
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{C_n^{(1)}}{C_n^{(2)}} =?? 
\end{align}

Comment: Write it as $\operatorname{He}_n$ (`\operatorname{He}_n`) instead of $H_{e_n}$ (`H_{e_n}`).